# Show/hide columns/rows in Local Report and auto-collapse on a specified direction?

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc, localreport

The problem is, if the columns or rows lie between others in the Tablix, all the hidden columns seem to be collapsed and other columns on the right are automatically shifted to the left, the same for rows, all the hidden rows seem to be collapsed and other rows on the bottom are automatically shifted to the top. But if the column is the first (or last) on the left (or on the right) and the row is the first (or last) at the top (at the bottom), all the other columns/rows seem to be fixed after that column/row being hidden.

Here is an illustration for what I want:

```
//Original table
Column 1     |    Column 2   |    Column 3
   11               21               31
   12               22               32
   13               23               33

//The problem after hiding Column 1
             |    Column 2   |    Column 3
                    21               31
                    22               32
                    23               33

//What I want (after hiding Column 1) looks like this:
Column 2   |    Column 3
   21               31
   22               32
   23               33
```

The same can be understood for rows.

Could you please give me some solution for this?

I don't have a clue on what to search for this kind of problem. Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is related to some rather poor usability in Report Builder and is quite understandable.

You are selecting individual cells (presumably, all cells in a row or col at once) and setting the 'hidden' property to true.

What you actually need to do is set the 'visible' property to false. When you do this, the whitespace will collapse as you expect. There is no need to change the hidden properly. The visible property you need can be found by right clicking on the grey column header at the top/left edge of the tablix and selecting the column/row visibility menu option.